# CSS min-height does not adjust background color and border

Tags: border, background-color, css

I'm having problems with this site I am building.  I need a fixed width so that I can do margin-left and margin-right auto (center the form item on my 'left window'.  Problem is that I'm trying to make this code modular so that it will work with any future forms I decide to create as well, meaning I need a variable height, depending on how many fields a form will need.

so to clarify the above statement, I'm trying to keep the fixed width and have a variable height (using min-height).  The problem is that the background color and div border are not shrinking or expanding along with the div size.  any ideas?

the site is here: http://traelid.com/news/createNews.php

here is my form code and my CSS code:

FORM:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../nicEdit/nicEdit.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
</script>

<div class='frmcontainer'>

    <div class='title'>TraeLid News</div>

  <div class='fill'>

        <div class='row'>

            <div class='frm lbl'>
                <label for='author'>Author:</label>
            </div>

            <div class='frm itm'>
                Auto Author
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class='row'>

            <div class='frm lbl'>
                <label for='subject'>Subject:</label>
            </div>

            <div class='frm itm'>
                <input class='itm itmtxt' type='text' name='subject' />
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class='row'>

            <div class='frm lbl'>
                <label for='content'>Content:</label>
            </div>

            <div class='frm itm txtarea' style='background-color:#fff;'>
              <textarea class='itm itmtxtarea ckeditor' name='content'></textarea>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class='row'>

            <div class='frm lbl'>
                <label for='tags'>Tags:</label>
            </div>

            <div class='frm itm'>
                <input class='itm itmtxt' type='text' name='tags' />
            </div>

        </div>

  </div>


</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .frmcontainer
    {

    text-align:center;

    width:750px;
    min-height:200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

    border-radius:10px;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style:solid;

}

.frm
{
    margin:5px;
}


.title
{
    clear:both; 

    width:750px;

    margin-bottom:24px;

    font-size:28px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:underline;
    font-variant:small-caps;

}

.row
{
    width:750px;
    height:auto;

    float:left;
    clear:both;
}

.lbl
{   
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;

    text-align:left;

    height:30px;
    width:150px;

    float:left;

}

/*Container and input styles*/

.itm
{
    text-align:left;

    height:25px;
    width:580px;        

    float:left;
}

.itmtxt
{
    width:576px;

    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}

.txtarea
{
    height:400px;
}

.itmtxtarea
{
    width:578px;

    height:343px;

    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
}
.nicEdit-panel 
{     
    background-color: #eee;
}
.nicEdit-selected 
{     
    background-color: #fff;
    word-wrap:break-word;;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nicEdit-main
{
    word-wrap:break-word;
    overflow:hidden;
    max-height:343px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on .frmcontainer add `overflow: hidden;`. [fiddle ex](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyomu/HKcd8/embedded/result/)

Comment: I was able to fix it with a position:absolute;

Comment: The problem was your floats, they don't resize the background automatically. adding `overflow: hidden;` will have it count. This works as because you don't have a height, it has nowhere to actually cut off.

Comment: @Kyomu, that makes a lot of sense as well.  Sometimes the CSS rules are just really odd to imagine

Comment: I actually removed my first solution and went with overflow because it seems cleaner, and my div was 'jumping' slightly with the position solution.  thanks for the help.

Comment: @DavidTorrey Glad I could help ;) But yah, when you understand css completely, your either a genius or insane in my book :)